# Kendo UI: Source Binding to Arrays of Primitive Objects

Tags: jquery, data-binding, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

Here is the original article from Kendo UI about binding to arrays of primitive objects: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/source#source-binding-to-arrays-of-primitive-objects

In my project I need to work with an array of strings as the values of input elements. And I was wondering if anyone knows why it's not possible to use the following template:

```
<script id="ul-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: this" />
        <a class="k-button textButton" title="Remove" data-bind="events: { click: removeValue }" href="\\#"><span class="k-icon k-i-close"></span></a>
    </li>
</script>
```

Instead of the one, provided in their docs:

```
<script id="ul-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <li data-bind="text: this"></li>
</script>
```

Whatever I tried it simply doesn't list the elements above with the primitive data like `[ "Coffee", "Tea", "Juice" ]`, but it works if there are objects instead of simple strings like `[ {product: "Coffee"}, {product: "Tea"}, {product: "Juice"} ]`, which is not preferable solution in my case.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: here is an example dojo for you. If you need further info let me know and I'll add an answer for you. https://dojo.telerik.com/iYuFOgef (assuming this is what you are after)

Comment: @DavidShorthose thanks for the sample, but what about this one? https://dojo.telerik.com/oWilIpeM

Comment: so the issue you have is that you are binding a click event that doesn't currently exist so the template is hitting that point and then breaking with an error which is why no other items are being loaded after the first item.

Comment: @DavidShorthose no, please re-check my DOJO link. Looks like you checked it at the time, when I was updating the code..

Comment: so this should work for you: https://dojo.telerik.com/aHOWIvAH please note that this isn't really the recommended way of doing it but handling primitive arrays seems to ignore a lot of the MVVM binding as it can't traverse up to the parent or bind to the parent functions like a complex datasource can.

Comment: @DavidShorthose Thanks, but it didn't work :( I just entered a full example into DOJO to be more clear, here it is: https://dojo.telerik.com/uWEdIroR/3 Thanks in advance.

Comment: @DavidShorthose or here is a bit extended version of your sample: https://dojo.telerik.com/AhajukUc Whenever I try adding a new string it threws a "TypeError t.set is not a function" and the newly added element is not getting saved to an array.. :(

Comment: I have updated the dojo here: https://dojo.telerik.com/ulIkozay this should work for you. It's not ideal but will work with your primitive array. Because the templating is looking for an object it's not sure how to set the values for the simple string item in the array so all I am doing is binding to a derived complex array that gets around this issue. If you need a more complete answer then I will add one for you

Comment: @DavidShorthose as I mentioned before, here: https://dojo.telerik.com/uWEdIroR/3 I entered almost full example of my code. At least structure. Could you please have a look at it? The one you edited (the freshest one) won't be a solution for provided example since listView element is appended by jQuery to the DOM and it looks a bit differently.